# gitlab-runner failing to pull image from google artifact registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, google-artifact-registry

I have created VM(container optimised OS) on gcp and installed gitlab runner with gitlab runner image
with command:
**docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always --log-driver none -v /home/<user_name>/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/<user_name>/.docker/config.json:/root/.docker/config.json:ro gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest**

after that i exec into the container and registered the runner for my repo(docker executor). the runner connected and picks the job perfectly with ruby:2.7 image as default image.

But now i have to use the image from my artifact registry in google as default image, so i changed the config.toml to make it as default image. Now the issue starts, the runner cant able to pull the image and job fails:
error:
**ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev//staging//:" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: Head "https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2//staging///manifests/": denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects//locations/europe-west1/repositories/staging" (or it may not exist) (manager.go:237:0s)**

I tried ,
FYI, I have given access from my VMs service account to the artifact registry and I am able to pull the image from my vm using docker pull, but in gitlab-ci the runner cant able to pull the image and throws above error.

i have run docker-credential-gcr configure-docker --registries europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev , **on my vm and after that i can pull image from artifact registry.
But why it is failing for my runner running on same VM**. can anyone please help me out here. Im stuck
Welcome for any suggestions